# Custom Puppet Type breaks puppet describe with "no such file to load -- json" (2.7)

Tags: ruby, puppet

I wrote a few custom Puppet types. As long as they all were used on the same node,

`puppet describe <my_custom_type>`

worked fine, displaying the documentation from CLI.

Then I wrote another custom type, but now I get

```
# puppet describe <my_new_custom_type>
Could not run: Could not autoload /var/lib/puppet/lib/puppet/type/<my_older_custom_type>: Could not autoload /var/lib/puppet/lib/puppet/provider/<my_older_custom_type>/<custom_provider>.rb: no such file to load -- json
```

A glimpse under the `/var/lib/puppet/lib/puppet` reveals that the 'missing' files are there. When I delete the old custom types' files under `/var/lib/puppet/lib/puppet`, then `# puppet describe <my_new_custom_type>` works fine.

Can someone advise an inexpensive workaround? Or I'm I overlooking something? I have to use Puppet v 2.7.something at the moment (not my personal choice), which will be upgraded in a matter of months, so if this is fixed in newer versions, I'd leave it as it is.

All aforementioned custom types/providers are working, of course. The isuue is limited to `puppet describe` functionality.

Comment: Is there a `require 'json'` in your older provider? Something in your recent changes seem to break that.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed, and I almost forgot it! Now, after installing ruby-json on the test machine, it works. Stupid me... But the weird part is - am I supposed to install a ruby-json package on _every single machine_ (instead of a handful, where it's used) in the entire puppet environment just for parsing the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Ruby gems that are required by one of your custom types must be provided for *all* your Puppet agents.

The agent invariably syncs the types and providers to your agents, because at the time of plugin sync, the agent cannot yet tell whether a type is required by the catalog or not.

If you can delegate the functionality to an external tool instead, Puppet will be able to discern that the provider just isn't suitable for most agents.

Comment: I know I'm breaking the rules, but how on Earth can I mark the question answered!? This message is displayed so briefly, that I still have no idea how to do it, with all those questions asked! By the way, thank you, Felix! :)